# SSH.Net SftpClient: do I need to call Disconnect within using block?

Tags: c#, using, idisposable, disconnect, ssh.net

In a code like this

```
using (var sftp = new SftpClient(_host, _userName, _password))
{
  sftp.Connect();
  // Do some work with sftp
  sftp.Disconnect();
}
```

Is sftp.Disconnect() call necessary or will using block (Dispose/Close/whatever) close connection automatically?

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need to call `Disconnect` within a `using` block.

`SftpClient` automatically calls the `Disconnect` method when disposing of the object.

See relevant source code:

https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/blob/7bdfc9e615b736b2762f5cd83c31a5f669663ff6/src/Renci.SshNet/BaseClient.cs#L409-L428